# Android studio: add library permanently

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a jar library on my libs folder and I add it as library and everything works. However, when I restart Android Studio the library is not added and I have to add it again.

Comment: Physically copy the file into the project? It's probably just making a file reference. But that's strange that it wouldn't save that location

Comment: What does it mean that you have to add again? Just put the jar in the libs folder and use gradle

Comment: @cricket_007 I have put into the project's libs folder

Comment: Okay, then Gradle should pick it up assuming you have it configured that way

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but my project is a libgdx one. Gradle doesn't seem to pick it, I have also tried adding compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])  to the Build.gradle